# Implementing WCF using netTCP protocol

Tags: .net, wcf, tcp

Having successfully got a WCF service and client to talk to one another using Http, I'm now trying to swtich it to netTcp so that I can encrypt the communication. However I'm having trouble getting the connection to establish under this protocol.

Having changed my App.config file on the service and deleted the service reference in the client project, I'm trying to re-add the service reference. Clicking on "discover" finds the service but on http with the address http://localhost:31284/MyService.svc which isn't an address I've specified anywhere: I assume it must be a default. If I try and add this service I get the error:

> The HTML document does not contain Web
>   service discovery information.
>   Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:31284/MyService.svc'.
>   Content Type application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8 was not supported by
>   service
>   http://localhost:31284/MyService.svc.
>   The client and service bindings may be
>   mismatched. The remote server returned
>   an error: (415) Unsupported Media
>   Type. If the service is defined in the
>   current solution, try building the
>   solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

In my app config I've specified the endpoint address as net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NameSpace.ApiServices.Server/MyService. If I put this address into the service reference box and try to connect to it or try to connect using WCF test client it also fails. Both kick up very similar errors:

> Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved:
>   'net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NameSpace.ApiServices.Server/MyService'.
>   Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NameSpace.ApiServices.Server/MyService.
>   The connection attempt lasted for a
>   time span of 00:00:02.0142014. TCP
>   error code 10061: No connection could
>   be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8732. 
>   No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:8732 If the service is defined in the current solution, try
>   building the solution and adding the
>   service reference again.

Not sure what's going on. Both are running on the same machine and my firewall is turned off. I checked netstat -a and couldn't see TCP listening on port 8732 but I have got the port sharing service turned on and enabled in my config. Which looks like this:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding portSharingEnabled="True" name="tcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security>
        <transport>
          <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="standard">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceMetadata />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service name="NameSpace.ApiServices.Server.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="standard">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding" contract="NameSpace.ApiServices.Server.IMyService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NameSpace.ApiServices.Server/MyService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I was asked for my client config:

```
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security>
            <transport>
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
            </transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address=""
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
            contract="NameSpace.Server.IUpdateCustomers" name="tcpBinding" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: @Matt: How do you host the service? It looks like you are hosting it in VS Studio Development web server which doesn't support net.tcp.

Comment: When your service is up and running, can you connect to it using the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) which comes with WCF?? You cannot connect to a net.Tcp service with a browser ....

Comment: I'm hosting it as a windows service - we have a specialist bit of software that picks up and hosts these services. I've stepped through as it sets up and I'm sure it's running the service. I cannot connect to the service using the WCF test client.

Comment: @Matt Thrower: if you cannot connect to it using WCF Test Client, then there's something decidedly wrong with your service/hosting. As long as you cannot do this, your service isn't working.... You should be able to connect to your service at the defined base address, or the MEX address - both don't work??

Comment: Ah, now that I come to inspect the log more cloesly, the hosting is going wrong. The error is ... There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:8732.  Make sure that you are not trying to use this endpoint multiple times in your application and that there are no other applications listening on this endpoint. ... but I thought port sharing was supposed to bypass that?

Comment: Port sharing will only bypass this if multiple WCF services are listening on the same port. Not if multiple applications are listening on the same port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally got to the bottom of it, if it helps anyone else. The serviceMetdata tag needs to have the httpGetEnabled attribute set to false:

```
 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
```

Otherwise, I assume, it's trying to spin up the endpoint on Http as well as Tcp and failing.

Answer (score 0):

After you created the tcp endpoint in the server, you have to make sure that you update the reference at the client end also. The first thing I would check is if the endpoints are compatible on the server and client. Check in app.config on the client side, and check that the tcp endpoint is set up properly here as well, and not just the old http endpoint.

Also, I believe that the mex endpoint for TCP cannot run on the same port as the service, so try exposing the mex endpoint on another tcp port than the main service endpoint.

Comment: Ah, okay - I thought that by adding the service reference the config on the client would update automatically? So you're saying that if the config isn't right, I can't even add the service reference? I'll paste in my client config while I hunt around.

Comment: Whenever you change the server, you will have to manually change the client proxy (the code generated when you choose Add Service) as well. Right clicking the service reference and clicking update usually does the trick. If the server and client do not have compatible endpoints, they will not be able to communicate.

Comment: But I can't even add the service reference at the moment :) But then again my service isn't being actively hosted by the look of it - see my comments above.

Comment: To add the reference you must first host it :). And remember that the builtin hosting in VS do not support exposing metadata over tcp, and that the tcp metadata port cannot be the same as the service port (if you haven't enabled port sharing)